# How to use IF CONDITION for combo box and compare its value?

Tags: php, if-statement, combobox

My code doesn't work!

```
 <option value="SEL">select</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 </select>
            <?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST['selection']) == TRUE) {
                if ($_REQUEST('selection') == 10) {

                    // $vari = $_POST['selection'];
                    //if(!empty(isset($vari))){
                     echo 'hi sarah';

                }
```

please help me  i can t fix it.I am newcomer in php.

Comment: Notice the difference.. `$_REQUEST['selection']` and `$_REQUEST('selection')`

Comment: You should give more details about the error you get.

Comment: Asu ,My code do not error. just don t work.don t print hi sarah.if condition don t work!

Comment: @Xorifelse . oh i change code .if (isset($_POST['selection'])){ if($_POST['selection']== 10 ){  }}

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is a superglobal array in PHP so it should be used as an array. E.g. use square brackets to access values of an array.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['selection'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['selection'] == 10) {
        echo 'hi sarah';
    }
}
```

Comment: @sarah, can you paste the whole form with the select and submit button as well?

Comment: .fixed ! i dont set submit button . :) thank you so much,my friend.i said ,i am newcomer :)